# Problem using `rake test`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake

I wonder how to setup testing in my rails apps. When I run `rake test`, first thing odd, it launch a bunch of `CREATE TABLE` against my dev. database (hum.. do not like this..). So I launch `rake test RAILS_ENV=test` and I even try `bundle exec rake test RAILS_ENV=test`. Now, the `CREATE TABLE` is against my test database but all fails with this error :

```
** Execute test:units
test/unit/category_test.rb:5:in `test': unknown command 't' (ArgumentError)
    from test/unit/category_test.rb:5:in `<class:CategoryTest>'
```

I have used basic generator in Rails 3 and do not change anything. So I have this in caterogy_test.rb :

```
require 'test_helper'

class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   # Replace this with your real tests.

   test "the truth" do
       assert true
   end
end
```

I use Rails 3.0.7 and basic config.

Any ideas ?

EDIT

I am becoming crazy, made a lot of tries, neither seems to work. When I start a new application with a few things, `rake test` works fine but when I try this on my current one, it launch always against my dev. db and do not work at all. I have tried to edit the test files, to revert them back, try to remove/setup test db with different ways, try different rake version, compare a lot of things on one side my current application and on the other a brand new one... Found nothing.. Help !

EDIT 2

Sounds lame, but is it normal that `rake` does the same thing than `rake test` ?

EDIT 3

Sounds odds, while I continue to work on what's wrong, I realize that every-time I run `rake test`, it does stuff on the dev environment and not the test one (watching the logs). It does this on my computer OSX and on our server FreeBSD for all the Rails 3.0.7 apps. Are you sure `rake test` is supposed to work on the test environment by default ?

EDIT 4

Please help!

EDIT 5 - SUMMARY

When running `rake test` in my computer or on our server in Rails 3.0.7 with different apps it does the following :

- run `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` migration against the dev. db.
- do not empty the dev. db.
- development.log gets written not the test.log
- also an issue with the error `unknowm comman 't'` with one specific app.

EDIT 6 - db config

Nothing change from the default yet : https://gist.github.com/1006199

EDIT 7

`rake db:test:prepare --trace` -> nothing break (but keep printing (first_time)
https://gist.github.com/1007340

With `RAILS_ENV="test"` for rake, everything goes fine. It write on the test logs.

`ruby -I test test/unit/category_test.rb` same erros than with `rake`, but no write on the dev. or test logs.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not accidentally put a space on line 5 of this test.  The error message is saying that on line 5 of the file test/unit/category_test.rb there is a command "t" that is not understood.  This could of happened if you accidentally typed a space (like t est) or had an extra "t" on the line

Comment: There MUST be something strange in your environment, since `rake test` usually knows that it should work in 'test' environment. I have never had to manually force the RAILS_ENV. Have you modified anything? Is this error reproduced when you create a new Rails app and just create the same, single resource?

Comment: not related to your question, but as you just start to get into testing, why not give RSpec a try?

Comment: try running `rake db:test:prepare --trace` also make sure your migrations are up to date (rake db:migrate).

Comment: Can you run the test file on its own? `ruby -I test test/unit/category_test.rb`

Comment: see my edits (seven now!) ;-)

Comment: The most important thing is what is line 5 of the test? And what changes have you made to environment files?

Comment: Show your test_helper.rb file

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I'm encountering a similar issue on a project I've taken over, and `rake test` for some odd reason is working against the development DB, despite everything looks correct (database.yml, test_helper.rb, etc).

Answer (score 3):

a bunch of unorderd answers:

- the "CREATE TABLE" statements usually means that your test_db is created from scratch (by default, before test task, a db:migrate is launched). are you sure they're called on dev_db?
  also check your config/database.yml to see if there's some typo (eg: using same table for test and dev environments)
- it looks like there's an error in some of your migration files (that 't' error remember blocks in migrations).
- "rake test" is the default task, that's why it's run when you just launch "rake" without arguments.

EDIT:

according on what I see on edits, from 5 and above, it looks like you have some issue with environment files. so try to double-check:
* config/environments/test.rb
* config/application.rb
* config/environment.rb

if **with RAILS_ENV="test", everything goes fine**, then I'm almost sure you have changed some default behaviour in your app (configs, env variables, any particular gem?)

also, in your test/test_helper.rb, add RAILS_ENV='test' at the beginning of file, this should force test environment.

Comment: Sounds odds, while I continue to work on what's wrong, I realize that every-time I run `rake test`, it does stuff on the dev environment and not the test one (watching the logs). It does this on my computer OSX and on our server FreeBSD for all the Rails 3.0.7 apps. Are you sure `rake test` is supposed to work on the test environment by default ?

Comment: can you paste your config/database.yml file?

Comment: what happens if you run: RAILS_ENV="test" bundle exec rake test ? (note that I put RAILS_ENV before the call). also check your test/test_helper.rb . it should have the first line with: ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

Answer (score 2):

I had that same error message, except to me it said: in `test': unknown command 'i' (ArgumentError).
The 'fix' or 'workaround' was to simply use:

```
$> bundle exec rake test
```

instead of using 'rake test'

Comment: For me, the `t` and `i` are whatever is the first letter of the test string name: `test 't...'`, `test 'i...'`.